# External Services - Nested object in response appears to be blank in Flow but is populated in Postman

Tags: visual-workflow, nested, external-services, response

There is already a [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309195/external-services-child-object-in-response-appears-to-be-blank-in-flow-but-is) asking the same, however it is still not responded.

I am using an **external service** and in the response, I am supposed to receive a **nested object** as per the following screenshot received by postman:

[image]

However, when I try to do the same from a **flow**, if I try to access it, I run into an exception and the **nested object is empty:**

[image]

There are the details of the action:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have used the External Service directly from apex with the following code and it is working as expected, so issue must be, somehow, in the flow mapping of the variables:

```
ExternalService.HungaryCompanyBillingAddresses service = new ExternalService.HungaryCompanyBillingAddresses();
ExternalService.HungaryCompanyBillingAddresses.getCompanyBillingAddress_Request request = new ExternalService.HungaryCompanyBillingAddresses.getCompanyBillingAddress_Request();

request.countryCode = 'HU';
request.customerId = '0011q000013f4ZmAAI';
request.taxNumber = '26139223-2-43';

ExternalService.HungaryCompanyBillingAddresses.getCompanyBillingAddress_Response response = service.getCompanyBillingAddress(
    request
);

ExternalService.HungaryCompanyBillingAddresses_getCompanyBillingAddress res = response.Code200;
ExternalService.HungaryCompanyBillingAddresses_getCompanyBillingAddress_billingAddress add = res.billingAddress;

System.debug(add.PostalCode); // 1117
System.debug(res.Taxno); // 26139223-2-43
```

**1. Why is this happening?**

**2. How do I get the response properly?**

Comment: Can you post more details about the action 'Get HU Company Billing Address'? Problem might like within this action's implementation.

Comment: Just added them

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Confirmed, the issue is with the flow mapping. In order to get it working I created a variable resource of apex-defined type, choosing the ExternalService autogenerated class, and used it in the output of 200.
Did the same as well for the billingAddress nested type:

[image]

[image]

[image]